# Reload page when deleting a product from mini-cart

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout, mini-cart

I was trying to make an script to reload the page when i delete a product from mini-cart.
The reason is because when i delete a product from it, if i am on the onestepcheckout, my summary don´t get reloaded, so i need to reload the full page to get again the price and the new shipping costs.

I see that `btn-close`appear on default.phtml on sns_ajaxcart, but with this sencente, i dont know what i have to do the reload after the onclick makes the changes on the cart.

This is my Element `<a>`

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php //echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
```

Any idea?

Comment: this works for me <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" class="cart-remove"> <span><?php echo $this->__('Remove'); ?></span> </a>

Comment: if the problem with the checkout page why don't you use this : <?php if (!$this->isOnCheckoutPage()): ?>

Comment: I just only wants to make a reload of the page on onestepcheckout if the person makes a delete from the mini-cart and it goes successfully
How could make with this @AhmedElAwadi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this on clean RWD template.

Line 158 replace:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getAjaxDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>" data-confirm="<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>" class="removex">
<?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
</a>
```

with

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?'), true) ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
```

It is working on every page, when you remove an item it refresh the page.